# For what natural number $n$ is the following inequality true: $2^n \geq 2\cdot n^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Can you solve this by using induction? The inequality is true for $n = 1$, but is false until $n = 7$. After the induction step I got

$$2^n \geq n^2 + 2n + 1.$$

If you take the limit as $n$ approaches infinity, you see that $P(n+1)$ is also true.

My answer: The inequality holds true for $n \geq 7$.

Comment: I was asking if it is a valid method for solving the problem. It didn't ask to show that the inequality is true, or to prove this claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality amounts to $2^{n-1}>n^2$, from which you deduce $2^n> 2n^2$. To prove the inductive step, it suffices to prove that for $n\ge 7$, $\,\,2n^2\ge (n+1)^2$. This amounts to $p(n)=n^2-2n-1 \ge 0$ for $n \ge 7$. As $p$ has a positive and a negative root and $p(3)>0$, both roots are less than $3$, hence $p(n)>0$ for all $n \ge 3$.

Comment: How did you end up with 2*n^2 >= (n+1)^2?

Comment: By transitivity: if $2^n>2n^2$ and $2n^2\ge (n+1)^2$, then…